# How to make XPage Save button work properly?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I have Save & Close button that is supposed to save current document and navigate to Home page.

The problem that it doesn't save the document (the doc is in edit mode). If I set button property submit="true" then it does save the doc by makes a replication conflict.

```
<xp:button id="buttonSaveClose">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[Save & Close]]></xp:this.value>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:actionGroup>
                <xp:saveDocument
                    var="#{javascript:document1}">
                </xp:saveDocument>
                <xp:openPage name="/Home.xsp">
                </xp:openPage>
            </xp:actionGroup>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete `<xp:saveDocument ... </xp:saveDocument>`.

You already set event handler's `save`-parameter to `true` and the document gets saved automatically. No need to save it a second time with a save action.

Comment: Well. So if it's not Submit button but the regular one then why Save Document action doesn't work? But I'm OK with Submit button.. It saves the doc but creates few replication conflicts. Is it because I have datasource document1 defined in xPage as well as in few custom controls?

Comment: Do you save document somewhere in custom controls?

Comment: No, I don't. .The Submit button is on custom Control and xPage and customControl have datasource set as NotesDocument document1. Should I keep/define it only in one place, e.g. in the root (xPage itself) ?

Comment: You can delete data source definition in custom controls if you use the same name ("document1" in your case) .

Comment: you're right. I removed all data document1 reference from all custom controls. No more replication conflicts. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`<xp:saveDocument
     var="#{javascript:document1}">
</xp:saveDocument>`

I'm pretty sure this should be `#{document1}` - it should be Expression Language rather than SSJS. Using a very basic simple action like `saveDocument` is good for your first demo database but, as you're seeing, there's no way to troubleshoot it or work out why it's not working. I'd recommend moving onto proper code as soon as possible, as I do in all training courses I run - so `#{javascript:document1.save();}`. You'll need this as soon as you want more control and it's not rocket science. Similarly, `#{context.redirectToPage("Home.xsp")}` replaces the other simple action.